# Spark local mode, worker threads and tasks

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

I use spark locally with local[2] in master and nodes conf.
On spark GUI I do see 2 cores for the worker threads.
[image]
On my code App I have added a `Thread.currentThread.getName()` inside a foreach action, and rather than seeing only 2 threads names I see `Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 27,5,main]` going up to `Thread[Executor task launch worker for task 302,5,main]`, why is there so many threads under the hood, and what would be precisely this notion of tasks ?